# Differentiability of a scalar field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Is $f(x,y,z)=x\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$ differentiable at the point $(0,0,0)$? Prove your assertion.

I'm pretty sure this function is actually differentiable at $0$. The problem is I'm unsure how exactly I should go about proving this. My understanding is that if the partial derivatives all exist at zero and are also continuous about zero, this would be enough to prove differentiability. How would I show these partial derivatives are continuous?

Note that the partial derivatives are all equal to zero at the origin.
With partial derivatives defined as:

(1) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$

(2) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}$

(3) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac{xz}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}$

Comment: Is the word *differentiable* missing from the statement of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if $f$ is $\textit{supposed}$ to be differentiable at the origin? (I guess this is implied by your inclusion of the phrase 'prove this assertion', but could you confirm?)  If you don't, then it's possible that $f$ isn't in fact differentiable at the origin, and simply showing that some of the partial derivatives are not continuous at the origin is not sufficient to prove non-differentiability.  You would have to prove that the tangent plane to the graph of $f$ is not a good linear approximation to the graph of $f$ at $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: It is in fact differentiable. All partial derivatives go to zero, though this is not enough to prove the fact that it is differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of a scalar field is the vector function defined by the gradient of that field. In order for $f$ to be differentiable, then the gradient would have to exist at the point in question. Find the gradient and then evaluate at $(0,0,0)$ to see if it exists.

I believe that $f_y$ and $f_z$ do not exist at $(0,0,0)$. Because these values do not exist, those functions are not continuous at the origin and therefore $f$ is not differentiable at this point.

Comment: You should probably add a little more to this answer: it is confusing as is.

Comment: Hmm, You're right, but I wonder if it is for the right reason? My text mentions that 1) the partial derivatives must exist at the point and 2) the partial derivatives must be continuous at the point. This seemed redundant to me as it would seem that the fact that the partial derivative exists implies that the partial derivative is continuous at that point. That is not the case. Perhaps it is enough to show the field is continuous at the point in question, but I see no such direct statements in my text.

Comment: Are you absolutely, 100% certain that all three of the partial derivatives exist at $(0,0,0)$?

Comment: @Algebraic Can you add what you think the partial derivatives are to your question?

Comment: @JoshuaCook I did this. The partial derivatives are all equivalent to zero at the origin.

Comment: @Algebraic Can you post the partial derivatives as functions of $x$, $y$, and $z$?

Comment: @JoshuaCook Yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30654/discussion-between-joshua-cook-and-algebraic).